# Magento - Command line indexer doesn't accept any command

Tags: magento, indexer

I stumbled upon a weird problem with Magento indexer. I tried to run it via command line, but, no matter what I write, I get back the help screen. Even if I run `php -f indexer.php info`, I just get the help screen, but no error messages, either on screen or in the system log. What should I check to find out why the indexer doesn't want to run?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. On the server where the script doesn't want to run, I have to use `php-cli` instead of `php`. It may have something to do with the server configuration.

I ran it as `php-cli indexer.php info` and I got the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

most likely your shell files have been modified. Next function is responsible for showing the help screen, check it out in your shell/abstract.php, should look like this:

```
protected function _showHelp()
{
    if (isset($this->_args['h']) || isset($this->_args['help'])) {
        die($this->usageHelp());
    }
}
```

Try debugging the `_args` array inside the function. If the array is not what you've provided, check out `_parseArgs` function in the same file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I compared the files with the ones extracted from a fresh installation and they are identical. It must be something else, then.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to separate your arguments with `--`?

```
php -f indexer.php -- info
```

Comment: I didn't need to use the "--" before the arguments, I just had to use `php-cli` instead of `php`.